# Transfering Web App From One AWS Account to Another: Rounte53 (DNS) and Webmail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-workmail, aws-route53

I have 2 AWS accounts, let's call them Account_A and Account_B.

I transferred my Web App from acccount A to account B.

The issue I have is with DNS. Although I transferred the domain name to account B (hopefully successfully) and although I defined A, MX, NS, SOA, TXT, CNAME records (I copy-pasted them from account A), when I enter the domain name in the browser, I cannot access the web app.
What I see in account B, Route 52:
[image]

I is worth noting that I can access the web app using public IP address (now running on account B).

Here is (an edited) snapshot of the entries I made in Route 53 (account B, new account):
[image]

By the way, I had to manually, update the name servers under "Route 53 --> Registered domains --> ". I did that by copying the name servers which were created automatically in the list of records.

On the other hand, I received from AWS the following e-mail:

> 5 days ago we detected that the TXT record information required to
> confirm ownership of the domain  in region Europe (Ireland)
> was no longer present. A notice was sent to you at that time.
>
> Since 5 days have elapsed, and the TXT record information has not been
> restored, Amazon SES will no longer consider  to be verified
> for purposes of Amazon SES and Amazon Pinpoint sending. If you wish to
> re-verify the domain, please reinitiate the verification process.
>
> For domain verification troubleshooting information, see
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/troubleshoot-verification.html
> .

I hope you can help me with the following questions:

- What precisely I need to make in order to activate my domain name? (When I enter domain name in the browser I would like to access my web app)
- Does the e-mail above from AWS refer to the domain name or to sending e-mails?
- Is it possible to transfer everything from Amazon Workmail from Account A to account B? If so, how can this precisely be done?

*(It would be great if some talented expert could provide a bit of explanation what has actually happened during the migration from AWS account A to AWS account B, so I get a better understanding.)*

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the real domain name?